# Locally activated oauth2 credentials not used by service on server

Tags: python-2.7, authentication, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, oauth2client

I have a server running ubuntu 14.04, running a flask-based website with some custom API functionality that I am testing. For this website, I have some code that uses oauth2client to connect to Youtube. This has to be authenticated manually, and is stored in a .json file:

```
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow

flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(self.YOUTUBE_CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
                               scope=self.YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE,
                               message=self.MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

storage = Storage("{}/my-oauth2.json".format(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
credentials = storage.get()

if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, self.args)
```

I have tested this code on a localhost server which was started using:

```
python run.py runserver
```

In this case, it works as expected. I have to authenticate only once, and the API-call succeeds.

```
>>> response = requests.post(url='http://localhost:5000/api', data=data)
>>> response.status_code
200
```

However, when running this as a uwsgi/nginx service on the server, the authentication is not accepted somehow. Checking whether the credentials file exists using `os.path.isfile(<filename>)` returns `True`, but the `credentials` variable ends up as `None`, and my server wants me to authenticate again. This obviously causes the API-calls I'm testing to time-out the first 2 times, and just fail every time after that. (This is expected because of how it tries to authenticate)

```
>>> response = requests.post(url=my_api_url, data=data)
>>> response.status_code
504
>>> response = requests.post(url=my_api_url, data=data)
>>> response.status_code
504
>>> response = requests.post(url=my_api_url, data=data)
>>> response.status_code
502
```

My question is:
Why do my stored credentials work for localhost, but not for my service? How do I fix it so that I can authenticate using localhost, and have my service on the server use these credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is quite the anti-climax.

During my many edits, I had changed the owner and rights of the file without realising it. Using `sudo chown :www-data my-oauth2.json` and `sudo chmod 755 my-oauth2.json` seems to have fixed the problem.

Always check your file read/write rights!